# trying to call await function on sequelize function

Tags: javascript, promise

I have created an async function *dbread* function, which authenticates database and setup table structure.

once this promise is resolved, then I  am calling insert statement & what I can observe here is that await call is not working expected.

Any pointer would be helpful.

```
 async function dbread() 
    {sequelize
        .authenticate()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
            sequelize.sync({force: true})
                .then(() => console.error('table ready'))
                .catch(err => console.error('sync failed', err))
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
        });

    }
    await dbread();
    console.log('start insert');
    //insert data
    batchModel.bulkCreate(testData, { returning: false })
        .then(() => console.error('inserted'))
        .catch(err => { console.error('insert failed', err) })
```

Comment: what is the context of the code you posted? you can't use `await` outside of a `async` function - the code you've shown apparently tries to do that - what error do you see in the console - something about `await` not being defined?

Comment: or is the problem that the `await` doesn't seen to `await` the promise that you think it should? Probably because `dbread` doesn't return anything ... try `return sequelize.authenticate()..... etc` - that's the problem with `is not working` - it's obvious that you are asking a question about code that `is not working` otherwise you wouldn't have a question - the devil is in the **detail**